# Trying to write to existing excel worksheet with Pandas ExcelWriter and getting bad zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas.excelwriter

Am trying to delete and write over an entire excel spreadsheet called `Data`. The code below returns "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file". How would I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file_loc = 'G:\\my_existing_excel_data.xlsx'

with pd.ExcelWriter(file_loc, datetime_format='m/d/yyyy') as writer:
    
    book = load_workbook(file_loc)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_loc, engine='openpyxl') 
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    
    date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'm/d/yyyy'})
    pct_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})
    wrap_fmt = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
    
    df.to_excel(writer, 'Data')
```

Full traceback as requested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\2/ipykernel_20416/3303582457.py", line 3, in <module>
    book = load_workbook(file_loc)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1324, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: I could be wrong here, but just by looking, it seems like you are opening the file multiple times: in the `with` statement, and then you load the workbook in openpyxl, and then re-do what is being done in the `with`. that looks not great, and so maybe the issue is coming from the file being opened/locked, but the error message isn't as descriptive as you want?

Comment: Windows will not normally let you write a file to the root folder on  `C:` so if that is what your code really says, change the location. Otherwise, [edit] your question to include the full stack trace.

Comment: @BoarGules That was not in the original code, just used as a place holder. Just changed the code to G://

Comment: I thought as much. Now, about that stack trace...

Comment: @BoarGules sorry I'm a bit unsure what you mean by stack trace... are you meaning traceback?

Comment: Yes. The entire block beginning `Traceback (most recent call last` and ending with the message you report. The message tells us *what* is wrong. The traceback tells you *where* and usually offers at least a hint as to *why*. That is why we insist on seeing it. Even if you don't understand it, that is not a reason to suppress it whan asking for help.

Comment: @BoarGules just updated the post